# django javascript not working

Tags: javascript, python, django, static

When I put the javascript tag in the `index.html` file, it works well but when I put it in the static directory, it does not work and there is also no error.

**views.py:**

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

**index.html:** (in `templates` directory)

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<script src={% static "/static/jquery.min.js" %}></script>
<script src={% static "/static/script.js" %} type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="content" id="ajax">

    {% include "svgmap.html" %}

</div>
```

**selection.html:** (in `templates` directory)

```
<div style="width:600px;height:300px;border:1px solid red;margin-top:190px;margin-left:50px;">

</div>
```

And in **svgmap.html** (in `templates` directory), I have added `onclick="loadDoc()"` to each `<path>` tag.

**script.js:** (in the app directory, `/map/static/`) and the `javascript.min.js` is in the same directory.

```
<script>
function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
           document.getElementById("ajax").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
       }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "/templates/selection", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try doing this simply by doing the below:

```
<script src="{{STATIC_URL}}<js_folder>/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{STATIC_URL}}<js_folder>/script.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Where

```
STATIC_URL = "/path_to_static_files"
```

In your example could be:

```
"/static/"
```

This approach is a bit more useful as you could have an external CDN URL too serving the static files, S3 or some other service.